# How to prevent editText from overlapping other view?

Tags: java, android

[image]I have created an android project to test out some of the `editText` behavior. So what I did was have two `editText` in a Relative Layout. One `editText` is above the other but then when the `editText` above gets too large, it overlap with the bottom editText. Is there a way to fixed this by shifting the other `editText` downward 1 line to make space?

Yes I am aware that you can limit the size of one of the `editText` to prevent it from getting too large but that is not what I want.

Comment: Can you share your xml/code?

Comment: umm do I have too? all I did really was  add have a relative layout have an editText and another one below the first editText. Then I just run the program. When I continue to type in the first editText, it eventually overlap with the bottom one.

Comment: yeah you really have to

Comment: we need to know what attributes you put in your edit text

Comment: ok let me post it. My editText like I said is nothing special all it is just drag and drop from the left side bar in android studio

Comment: @Wowzer you could set a padding to the top edittext or the bottom. That would give you space between them

Comment: yah it would actually but the problem is that once you type and type with text the top edittext string will over lap onto the bottom edit text. Doesn't matter if you have padding. What I want is a way to shift the view downward sort of to just make more room for the top edit text

Comment: try adding `marginTop` attribute in second EditText...

Comment: @Wowzer include this for your second edittext: `android:paddingTop="10dp"`

Comment: scrollbar for recyclerview may help, as the view should stretch now.

Otherwise scrollbar and equal size for both editText in a linerlayout?

Comment: I have added padding and have try the margin top doesn't work I am so frustrated. Btw thanks for answering

Comment: Wait does a linearlayout makes to bottom editText shift downward to make room for the top editText?

Comment: What exactly do you want, 1 EditText 1 line without anything and then another EditText?

Comment: Yes its better using LinearLayout, If you won't get any trouble because of that

Comment: What I want is to have an editText above another edit Text. Then I can type All I want onto the top editText and the bottom editText would shift downward to make room for the string in the top editText.

Comment: @Wowzer I tried your layout and it's doing what you want.

Comment: weird mine won't work. Let me update android studio and see

Comment: I tried your code, copied it identically and ran it in Android Studio, it automatically does the behavior you desire, I think since you already included the layout_below attribute, it automatically does that. Have you tried Clean Build your code?

Comment: @Wowzer just a suggestion, remove the + sign in your `layout_below` of second edit text. you already added that id so no need for the + sign

Comment: Wow turn out it was my android studio. I update and everything works thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this

```
<ScrollView>

  <RelativeLayout> 

    <EditText></EditText>
    <EditText android:marginTop = "10dp"> </EditText>

  </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**OR**

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <ScrollView> 

    <EditText></EditText>
    <EditText android:marginTop = "10dp"> </EditText>
  </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use LinearLayout (with orientation=vertical) if you want to stack them but in case you want to stick with RelativeLayout this is how you can do it. The key is `android:layout_below` attribute.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="baby"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edittext1"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```